# Why we need to test fake code?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, stub

Maybe my question will sound silly to someone, but anyway: why we need to test fake code?

I read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) and I can not understand why we need to test units which we initialize by ourself including returning values and e.t.c. If I use fake object it will always return what I want to (if I use AAA pattern) and if logic of my real code will change and will be wrong, unit test with mock or stub don`t show that. Am I wrong?

Or unit-tests need only to documenting how need to work with classes or libraries?

Comment: Don't fake the code being tested, fake the code (really the results/behavior) that the code being tested depends upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point in mocking is *not* to mock the objects you are going to test but to mock those objects which the object under test depends on, like:

TestRunner -> ObjectUnderTest -> MockedObject1..n

Here you test the behavior of ObjectUnderTest which needs some other objects to work. The latter objects are not subject to the current test, and so are mocked for this test instance.

Comment: Oh, I see now, thanks. Maybe my misunderstanding is because of examples from book is not really indicative.